# SVG balls animated along a path

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am trying to make SVG dots/balls run along a path. What i am struggling with is using multiple animations on one page. The dots all seem to listen to the first path and I would like each set to be unique. What i have below.

Also I am inserting this code inside an html code block on a wordpress page so I like how this doesn't require the head css style and the traditional css transform codes etc and is nicely contained to use inside svg tag. It works perfectly but when i use another wave further down the page is listens to the first path motion.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="3000" height="400"  viewBox="0 0 3000 400">
  <path d="M0,58.5c201.2,0,296.3,141.4,498.4,141.4S801.6,58.5,999.8,58.5s302.9,141.4,500.2,141.4
    s306.3-141.4,502.5-141.4s305.2,141.4,499.4,141.4c194.2,0,299.2-141.4,498.1-141.4"
        stroke="#444444" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="wire"></path>
  <circle cx="" cy="" r="8" fill="#444444">
    <animatemotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.1 0.4 0.8 0.9">
      <mpath xlink:href="#wire"></mpath>
    </animatemotion>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="" cy="" r="4" fill="#444444">
    <animatemotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.1 0.2 0.8 0.9">
      <mpath xlink:href="#wire"></mpath>
    </animatemotion>
  </circle>
</svg>

    
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="3000" height="400"  viewBox="0 0 3000 400">
  <path d="M0,135.5c501.6-4.4,502.9,150.6,1004.5,146.2c501.6-4.4,500.2-159.3,1001.8-163.7
    c501.6-4.4,502.9,150.6,1004.5,146.2"
        stroke="#222222" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="wire"></path>
  <circle cx="" cy="" r="8" fill="#222222">
    <animatemotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.1 0.4 0.8 0.9">
      <mpath xlink:href="#wire"></mpath>
    </animatemotion>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="" cy="" r="4" fill="#222222">
    <animatemotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.1 0.2 0.8 0.9">
      <mpath xlink:href="#wire"></mpath>
    </animatemotion>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/Tuff-Lover/pen/ZEodgPY

Comment: all id values must be unique, yours aren't.

Comment: thanks man just sussed that out, so good this little code for what i need.